# Open more than 10 files matching a pattern with vim's CLI

Tags: vim

Is there way (from the CLI) to increase the number of files that can be opened using vim's `-p` option?

E.g.

`$ vim -p lib/**/*.rb # opens 10 files in tabs`

Is there a way to alter the above command such that it will open all (or more than 10) files?

Alternatively, is there a better way to open the collection of files (in tabs) from the command line?

Comment: Yes, there's a better way: don't use tabs. Tabs may be OK when you have 2 or 3 of them but, above a threshold that depends on the width of your terminal and a few other factors, they quickly become useless. You should simply use buffers instead.

Comment: romainl, I can see how the tabs' labels become unreadable; however, I can still navigate tabs and edit the files. Besides compacted labels, in what way are the tabs rendered useless?

Comment: Because the only benefit of tabs over just using buffers is that they display the name of the tab (sort of) and, thus, help navigation. Once you have made the tab labels too short to be read or you have so many of them that some are hidden, you are left with zero benefit. Also Vim's tabs are not tied to a specific buffer, they are designed as "workspaces", not buffer-proxies, and should be used accordingly. Just load all your files and navigate with `:bnext` and `:bprevious` (same as `:tabnext`/`:tabprevious`) or, better, with `:b <Tab>`.

Comment: @romainl I disagree about tabs having no benefits. You can't switch from a buffer unless you save it first, but you can easily make changes to multiple tabs without saving.

Comment: @imgx64: No, you *believe* that "you can't switch from a buffer unless you save first", but that's because the `hidden` option is off by default. Turn it on and forget "tabs as file proxies".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change this by setting the tabpagemax option in your .vimrc:

```
set tabpagemax=15
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can increase the `tabpagemax` by

```
$ echo "set tabpagemax=30" >> ~/.vimrc
```

The better solution would be to use the same command without `-p`, opening all matching files in buffers:

```
$ vim lib/**/*.rb # opens all matching files in buffers
```

One can then navigate between files in vim's buffer using `:bnext` and `:bprevious`.